# Android- How to get custom permission string defined in Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-package-managers

```
<permission
        android:name="com.example.myPermission"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />
```

If I defined a permission like this and use this permission to an activity A. Then I want to check if an app have this permission, so I use `PackageManger` and the `checkPermission(permissionString, packageName)` method to check. The problem is I don't want to use straight string for `permissionName`, is there any way I can get the permission string like `Manifest.permission.xxxx`?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is no `Manifest.permission` value for your custom permission, because `Manifest.permission` is part of the platform, and ~1.5 billion Android devices do not know about your app.

You can try using a string resource for the permission name, referring to that resource both from `<permission>` and from your Java code.

Comment: Thanks!! I will use the string resource.